# Using Ionic open App Info in device settings

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have one ionic app in which it is asking for Location permission from user

If user clicks on "Don't allow for multiple times" then android doesn't allow me to ask for this permission any more hence as i solution i decided to show user a message to compulsary enable the permission and if user agrees and want to give permission then i will take user to App's Info page in Android.

From where user can enable the permission and can access the features of app.

Now, the issue is i want to redirect the user to app settings if he press okay to turn on the permission

Can anyone please confirm if this possible and how can we do this ?

Comment: Just use a simple route to go to your app settings. No plugin needed.

Comment: here by app settings i mean into the device settings i should  get redirected to my apps permission settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got how can we achieve this,  use below capacitor plugin,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-native-settings

For Android :

```
NativeSettings.openAndroid({
  option: AndroidSettings.ApplicationDetails,
});
```

ApplicationDetails options of Android will take you to your APP settings

Comment: DO you require any kind of permissions listed in the AndroidManifest for this to work? Just tried that on the emulator and nothing happens

Comment: No permission needed. can you please once check in the real device